# Dynamic Key for SortedList<Key, Value>

Tags: c#

I am having the following class

```
public class MyDictionary : SortedList<int, MyData>
{
}
```

At the moment the `Key` in the `SortedList` represents a year number, e.g. 2014, 2015, 2016 etc. The `Value` represents the data for the year.

Now I have a new requirement saying that having a `Value` per year is not enough and this class should support a finer granularity.

The new granularity looks like this:

- Yearly
- Quarterly
- Monthly
- Weekly
- Daily

Of course one instance of `MyDictionary` should represent one time frame, e.g. `SortedList<Yearly, MyData>`, `SortedList<Monthly, MyData>`.

The data that goes into `MyDictionary` spans over several years. That means that I cannot use, e.g. the number of a month in a monthly granularity. Example:

```
2014-12
2015-01
2015-02
...
2015-12
```

As you can see the number 12 is twice in the list.

My problem is, that I don't know what data type to use for the `Key` and how to access the `Values` in `MyDictionary` to meet the new requirement.

Any ideas?

**Modification from 24.02.2016:**

I must add a little more information to the original question.

1. The granularity is known at runtime only
2. The access to the `Values` via the `array indexer []` must be runtime optimised. It will be called millions of times in a very short period of time.
3. The class that uses `MyDictionary` uses a `DateTime` object to access the `Values`. Example:

```cs
public class ClientClass
{
    public void AccessMyDictionary(DateTime date)
    {
        MyData data = MyDictionary[date.Year];

        // Do something with data
    }
}
```

It looks to me that the most obvious thing to do is to have `DateTime` as an indexer data type. Then create an indexer in the `MyDictionary` class to take care of granularity. Example:

```cs
public enum Period
{
    Yearly,
    Quarterly,
    Monthly,
    Weekly,
    Daily
}

public class MyDictionary
{
    private Period period;
    private SortedList<DateTime, MyData> sortedList;

    public MyDictionary(Period period)
    {
        this.period = period;
        sortedList  = new SortedList<DateTime, MyData>();
    }

    public MyData this[DateTime i]
    {
        get
        {
            // Implement here an algorithm for granularity, similar to the one of Tomas Lycken in the 1st answer
        }

        set
        {
            // Implement here an algorithm for granularity, similar to the one of Tomas Lycken in the 1st answer
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think? Is that runtime optimised?

Many thanks
Konstantin

Comment: If your intention is to just sort the data based on the mentioned criteria, I feel you should use List<MyData> instead of Sorted List, then expose a method which will do sorting based on the parameters based.

Comment: Why not just use `DateTime` as key? Then you could do a query based on your lookup requirement (eg. year, month, etc.)

Comment: Hi @derape,
I like the idea of the data type being `DateTime`. How would the query look like? Could you please give me one example?

Answer (score 2):

I would define some new value objects for the various granularities, all deriving from a common base class `Period`. You can then use as these keys. For example,

```
public abstract class Period { }

public class Quarter : Period
{
    public int Quarter { get; }
    public int Year { get; }

    public Quarter(int year, int quarter)
    {
        if (year < 1800 || year > DateTime.UtcNow.Year)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(year));
        }

        if (quarter < 1 || quarter > 4)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quarter));
        }

        Year = year;
        Quarter = quarter;
    }
}
```

And of course you'd define similar types for `Year` (which only has one property), `Month` (which has a year and a month, and the month must be between 1 and 12), `Week` (where validation becomes a little more tricky, since not all years have the same number of weeks), `Day` (don't forget to allow for leap years!).

Then, you also define equality and hashing for these types so that if their properties are equal, they are equal. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/38055) is a good read on the topic!) For `Quarter`, I'd do something like

```
public class Quarter
{
    // properties and constructor ommitted

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is Quarter))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var quarter = (Quarter)other;

        return quarter.Year == Year && quarter.Quarter == quarter;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            // The two hard-coded digits below should be primes,
            // uniquely chosen per type (so no two types you define
            // use the same primes).

            int hash = (int) 2166136261;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ Quarter.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ Year.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how else you're going to use these, you might also want to [override `==` and/or `!=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx).

Now, these types are fully usable as keys in the dictionary, so you can do

```
var quarterlyReport = new SortedList<Quarter, Data>();
```

If you want to avoid having to define `Equals` and `GetHashCode` manually, most associative collections in .NET have a constructor which takes an equality comparer for the key type, that handles this for you. `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` [has one too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132323(v=vs.110).aspx), so instead of overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` above you could create a pendant type for each period like

```
public class QuarterComparer : IComparer<Quarter>
{
    int IComparer<Quarter>.Compare(Quarter p, Quarter q)
    {
        return p.Year < q.Year
            ? -1
            : p.Year == q.Year
                ? p.Quarter < q.Quarter
                    ? -1
                    : p.Quarter == q.Quarter
                        ? 0
                        : 1
                : 1;
    }

    public int Compare(Quarter p, Quarter q)
    {
        return (this as IComparer<Quarter>).Compare(p, q);
    }
}
```

and pass this to the constructor of the sorted list:

```
var quarterlyData = new SortedList<Quarter, MyData>(new QuarterComparer());
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. It looks great, but I don't know the granularity at compile time yet. Only at runtime. But you could not have known this. --> See my modification to the original question.

However I will probably use some of your ideas in the final solution.

Thanks!